# How to load an array of tuples in a SwiftUI List

Tags: arrays, swift, swiftui

The following code produces the error `Type cannot conform to 'Hashable'`.

How can I load an array of tuples to a SwiftUI List?

#### Code

```
import SwiftUI
struct TestingGeneral: View {

    let users: [(name: String, age: Double)] = [
        ("Jeff", 25),
        ("Nathan", 18)
    ]
   
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            List {
                ForEach(users, id: \.self) { user in
                    Text(user.name)
                    Text("\(user.age)")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### Error

> Type '(name: String, age: Double)' cannot conform to 'Hashable'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `self` in a `ForEach` is not very compatible with SwiftUI

```
ForEach(users, id: \.self) { user in
```

You should always have a unique variable. SwiftUI is all about identity.

```
ForEach(users, id: \.name) { user in
```

Check out Demystify SwiftUI from #wwdc21
https://developer.apple.com/wwdc21/10022

Comment: It made the trick. Thank you for the video link.

Comment: @fs_tigre glad to help. If I answered the question do you mind clicking on the green checkmark to accept?

Comment: Done. I tried but it doesn't allow you to mark it as answered until 3 or 5 minutes after you posted the answer.